# Bizarre behavior in mysql running a query

Tags: mysql, sql

My intention was to run this query in mysql:

```sql
update my_users set isLocked=1 where categoryId=10;
```

But I accidentally typed a dash (-) instead of the equal sign(=). So the query looked like this:

```sql
update my_users set isLocked=1 where categoryId-10;
```

This produce issues because it ran for everybody instead of just that belong to the category 10
Wondering why the 2nd call do not produce any errors and prevent the execution ?

Comment: It's always possible to deduct 10 from something, so column minus 10 always evaluates as true

Answer (score 3):

Yup . . . You have an arithmetic expression, which is interpreted as:

```
categoryId - 10 <> 0
```

So, it doesn't update *all* rows -- just all rows where `categoryId` is not 10.

Ooops.  This is a consequence of MySQL helping you by treating booleans as interchangeable with integers, with `0` for false and all other values for true.

You *might* be able to prevent this using [`sql_safe_updates` mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates).  However, I'm not sure if the mode actually checks that you make an explicit comparison on the key.

Comment: Thank you, the arithmetic expression explain this. And this is also actually scary forgot that mysql do not require spaces between expressions.